# Cancancan gem defining ability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I am trying to define an ability where a logged in participant can manage projects based on the invites.

Code below yields an error when I access a project `undefined method project' for #<Project:0x007f2c998410>`

```
can :manage, Project, :project=>{:invite=>{:participant=>{:user => {:id => user.id}}}}
```

**TL;DR**

The table relationships are below.

```
projects --> invites <-- participants <--users
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the `has_manny :invites` relation in the supplier Model

Answer (score 0):

The hash format was incorrect. This works:

`can :manage, Project, invites: {participant: {:user_id => user.id}}`